# Psychonauts Humble Indie Bundle V error

Tags: 12.04, games

When I try to load Psychonauts it crashes and this is the result I get when running from teminal. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
shaneo@laptop:~$ cd psychonauts/
shaneo@laptop:~/psychonauts$ ./Psychonauts 
STUBBED: fix up the rest of the SSE code first at DetectSSESupport
(/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFMath/MathGeneral.cpp:32)
STUBBED: write me? at SetPCLanguage (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/game/luatest/UnixMain.cpp:120)
STUBBED: fix up the rest of the SSE code first at DetectCPUCaps (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/game/luatest/Game/PCGameApp.cpp:223)
STUBBED: check LANG envr var at _GetDefaultGameLanguage (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/game/luatest/Game/GameApp.cpp:171)
Console created
Save  path: /home/shaneo/.local/share/Psychonauts
Write path: WorkResource
STUBBED: inline asm at SSEMul_4x4_4x4_2arg
(/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFMath/Matrix.cpp:710)
STUBBED: inline asm at SSEMul_4x4_4x4_3arg (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFMath/Matrix.cpp:698)
 ******** unit test failed ********
Transport started
DaveD: NCListenSocket: Listening on port 40001
STUBBED: VK_* at InitInputNames (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DirectX/SDLInput.cpp:1173)
No joysticks detected
STUBBED: multisampling? at initPlatform (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFGraphics/OpenGLGraphics.cpp:1667)
ERROR: Missing required OpenGL extensions:
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
Start Up completed in 0.13 seconds
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
shaneo@laptop:~/psychonauts$
```

Comment: What graphics card and which driver?

Comment: What version of the game are you using? A new one was uploaded a few hours ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Psychonauts can definitely run on Intel Cards under Linux, you just have to force the card to allow s3tc textures. To do this under the command line, you would use:

```
force_s3tc_enable=true ./Psychonauts
```

And it should work. You might want to edit the .desktop file that the installer created so that it will point to a psychonauts.sh file that contains this command. That way you could still run the game from the app menu.

My .sh file looks like this:

```
cd /home/mike/Custom/psychonauts
force_s3tc_enable=true ./Psychonauts
```

And in the .desktop file I changed the exec from `"/home/mike/Custom/psychonauts/Psychonauts"` to `sh /home/mike/Custom/psychonauts/psychonauts.sh`

The **sh** command is absolutely necessary here, or else the game won't load properly and your desktop might lock up.

A word of warning: while the game will run on an integrated Intel graphics card, it probably won't run very WELL. You can adjust graphics settings in-game to try and improve performance, but it'll still be at least a little choppy.

Comment: It works, but it crashes on some cutscenes...

Comment: Works very well thank you. Will the same trick work for Amnesia? The game will load up until it asks for a name and then crashes.

Comment: BrianXP7: I've found the Linux port of Psychonauts to be kind of unstable and a bit weak in the performance area as well. That's just the unfortunate nature of the port - it was not done all that well. The Windows version under Wine might perform far better.

@shaneo I have not tested Amnesia myself yet. But I **can** confirm that it fixes the black screen problem in Bastion.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your graphics card is not good enough to play this game, as indicated by this error:

`ERROR: Missing required OpenGL extensions:
- GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc`

It's also possible that you neglected to install proprietary drivers for your card, if it is Nvidia or ATI.