# Can't start Psychonauts game -- segfault

Tags: 12.04

This looks similar to [Psychonauts Humble Indie Bundle V error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145522/psychonauts-humble-indie-bundle-v-error) but I don't have the ERROR message (missing GL capability) and its solution does not work for me.

When trying to run Psychonauts from the Humble Indie Bundle on my x86_64 laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 I get the following output:

```
<bjn@segnus:/usr/local/games/psychonauts>$ ./Psychonauts
STUBBED: fix up the rest of the SSE code first at DetectSSESupport (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFMath/MathGeneral.cpp:32)
STUBBED: write me? at SetPCLanguage (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/game/luatest/UnixMain.cpp:120)
STUBBED: fix up the rest of the SSE code first at DetectCPUCaps (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/game/luatest/Game/PCGameApp.cpp:223)
STUBBED: check LANG envr var at _GetDefaultGameLanguage (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/game/luatest/Game/GameApp.cpp:171)
Console created
Save  path: /home/bjn/.local/share/Psychonauts
Write path: WorkResource
STUBBED: inline asm at SSEMul_4x4_4x4_2arg (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFMath/Matrix.cpp:710)
STUBBED: inline asm at SSEMul_4x4_4x4_3arg (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DFMath/Matrix.cpp:698)
******** unit test failed ********
STUBBED: VK_* at InitInputNames (/home/icculus/projects/psychonauts/Source/CommonLibs/DirectX/SDLInput.cpp:1220)
No joysticks detected
Transport started
DaveD: NCListenSocket: Listening on port 40001
SDL_SetVideoMode() failed: Failed loading libGL.so.1
Start Up completed in 0.06 seconds
[1]    9718 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./Psychonauts
<bjn@segnus:/usr/local/games/psychonauts>$
```

Output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M-E LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
02:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well you still get `Failed loading libGL.so.1` which is due to openGL

Comment: And how do I fix that? libgl1 is installed, which is the closest thing I can see in the package list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to download the patch 0.4 and extract it to the Psychonauts folder from this [link](http://treefort.icculus.org/psychonauts/).
I had some bug and with this patch i solved everything.

PS: The psychonaut folder is in /opt/Psychonauts if you installed it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: That plus the force_s3tc_enable=true environment variable mentioned in http://askubuntu.com/questions/145522/psychonauts-humble-indie-bundle-v-error did the trick -- thanks. Sadly it's unplayably slow on my laptop anyway.