# How do I install S3TC?

Tags: 12.10, games, steam

I recently installed steam on ubuntu 12.10 and when i try to load tf2 this error appears: "Required OPenGL extension "GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc" is not supported. Please install s3tc texture support

Answer (score 12):

you can try the trick described in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145522/psychonauts-humble-indie-bundle-v-error), open a terminal and before running steam force the load of the extension so:

```
force_s3tc_enable=true steam
```

This if steam is the command from the terminal to run it ;)