# Possible Graphics Problem Playing Out Of Reach

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games, steam

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to play a Steam game. My system does meet the minimum system requirement and I have no problem playing the game itself, just some minor graphics problem.

Is there a way to find out if my graphics drivers are up to date?

The game I am trying to play is *Out Of Reach* and my graphics card is Nvidia 9600GSO 512mb.

Pictures are for the problem I am having in the game on any setting for graphic quality. I have also already talked to the developer about this issue. The problem is only on the ground my player is standing on and small surrounding area.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in game settings about a compression? It looks like s3tc [patent issue](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/S3TC/) which [could be overcome though](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231176/how-do-i-install-s3tc). What is the developer said by the way?

Comment: The developer just asked about getting the .log information for the game nothin since. As for the in game settings it doesn't have much and as far as compression nothing about that, it is more for detail distance I have tried to lower the settings for that but still same thing.

Comment: Do you have «Nouveau» NVidia driver *(i.e. the one shipped by default with the system)*? Have you try [installing the proprietary one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)?

Comment: Ok I see now what your saying I have a GeForce 9600 GSO what driver would I need.

Comment: It depends. Despite the article I linked saying about missing 3d acceleration, latest unstable Mesa drivers have decent performance *(at least for radeon, but I think nvidia too)*. But since you have this strange glitch, I'd advice you to try two things: first try adding and upgrading to [PPA Xorg-edgers](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers) *(relatively latest Mesa drivers)*. If it wouldn't work, try then installing proprietary drivers *(for an example you could look the link I left in prev. comment)*.

Comment: Ah, one more thing — you could try running the game with `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` set. What it does is uses software rendering of Mesa — the point of that is a check: if the problem disappear, most probably it is a fault of drivers. For example `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 xinit /usr/bin/wine h3hota.exe -- :1 vt8` is the command I used until recently to play Heroes3 with my gf *(I did use unstable drivers, and until recently there was a bug causing the game to hang; thankfully, it is very old game. The command runs the game in a separate XServer, Ctrl+Alt+F7/8 to switch)*.

Comment: It was quite easy to install the driver , just by hitting the supper button then searching additional drivers  from there it searched and I was able to install it but still haven’t played the game yet.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that it solved the problem and the game runs flawless only around 20 FPS but still its much better now. Thanks

Comment: Ok, reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be a driver bug. To exclude it you could run the game with Mesa software rendering enabled, just set the variable `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` when starting the game, and see if the problem persist. If this is the case *(though if that didn't work too)*, you could either try upgrading to latest unstable Mesa drivers by adding [Xorg edgers PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers) *(alternatively [Oibaf PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers))*, or install proprietary NVidia drivers.